# Labeling Subplots in Matlab

Tags: matlab, subplot

An example of subplots is given here:

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-16BSF/?product=SL&solution=1-16BSF

```
figure(1)
surf(peaks(10))
colorbar

figure(2)
mesh(peaks(10))
colorbar

figure(3)
contour(peaks(10))
colorbar

figure(4)
pcolor(peaks(10))
colorbar

% Now create destination graph

figure(5)
ax = zeros(4,1);
for i = 1:4
ax(i)=subplot(4,1,i);
end

% Now copy contents of each figure over to destination figure
% Modify position of each axes as it is transferred

for i = 1:4
figure(i)
h = get(gcf,'Children');
newh = copyobj(h,5)
for j = 1:length(newh)
posnewh = get(newh(j),'Position');
possub = get(ax(i),'Position');
set(newh(j),'Position',...
[posnewh(1) possub(2) posnewh(3) possub(4)])
end
delete(ax(i));
end
figure(5)
```

How would one add labels to the subplots in this example? Just adding 'figure 1' 'figure 2' etc would be instructive.

Comment: What kind of label do you want to add?

Comment: In my application, I'm creating histograms of the contents of a set of files, and want to label each histogram with a filename, i.e. `'CFZ12'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two lines at the end of the script like this:

```
string = {'Figure 1','Figure 2','Figure 3','Figure 4'}; %%% or any titles you want
for i = 1:4
figure(i)
title(string{i}) %%% add this line
h = get(gcf,'Children');
newh = copyobj(h,5)
for j = 1:length(newh)
posnewh = get(newh(j),'Position');
possub = get(ax(i),'Position');
set(newh(j),'Position',...
[posnewh(1) possub(2) posnewh(3) possub(4)])
end
delete(ax(i));
end
figure(5)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think many people will come across this entry in order to find a way to simply add a title to a subplot without any copying (as I did). For this case, it can be done very easily as already stated by Sanjay Manohar:

```
figure(1)

subplot(4,1,1)
surf(peaks(10))
title('Figure 1') % must come AFTER the plot command
colorbar

subplot(4,1,2)
mesh(peaks(10))
title('Figure 2') % must come AFTER the plot command
colorbar

subplot(4,1,3)
contour(peaks(10))
title('Figure 3') % must come AFTER the plot command
colorbar

subplot(4,1,4)
pcolor(peaks(10))
title('Figure 4') % must come AFTER the plot command
colorbar
```

The important part here is (and I think that's where most of the errors come from) that the `title`-command must come after the actual plot command. If it was written before plotting the graph, the title would not appear!

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use

```
figure(5)
subplot(4,1,1)
title('first figure')
subplot(4,1,2)
...
```

at the end of the script? Or have i missed something?

Alternatively use `title` in the original figures e.g.

```
 figure(1)
 surf(peaks(10))
 title('first figure')
```

Comment: Your first proposal clears the figures (at least in some versions of Matlab). The second does not work, because the titles are not copied